# Mapping springboot property to JAXB namespaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I have the following snippet of code:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "loginRequest", namespace = "http://www.something.com/a")
public class LoginRequest {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.something.com/b")
    private String hello;
}
```

I want to have the namespace in my `application.yaml` file in order to change that code to this:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "loginRequest", namespace = "${something.namespace.login}")
public class LoginRequest { 
    @XmlElement(namespace = "${something.namespace.hello}")
    private String hello;
}
```

More ideally, I want to use a Properties object for the values, such that I can have:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "loginRequest", namespace = "#{namespaces.login}")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LoginRequest {
 @XmlTransient
 public Namespaces namespaces;

 @Autowired
 public LoginRequest(Namespaces namespaces) {
     this.namespaces = namespaces;
 }

 @XmlElement(namespace = "#{namespaces.hello}")
 private String hello;
```

In the last two examples, the pojo is a Spring bean that is instantiated via the `@Bean` annotation in an `@Configuration` class.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work, as the values are never injected. Is there a way for me to inject these namespaces from the `application.yaml` file?

Comment: Jaxb, as all xml/json binders, doesn't have that kind of flexibility. You could serialize the objects yourself with JDOM. Also, I'm not sure if you're aware that your idea is fundamentally irreconciable with deserializing XML into your objects.